# Linq grouping get multiple properties

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to group by CategoryId and display the CategoryId + the Name property of the group, I need help modifying this code so the Name property can be displayed, check out view below th see what I mean.

**Database**

**ItemCategory**
int ItemId
int CategoryId

**Category**
int CategoryId
int? ParentId
string Name

```
var itemcategories = db.Fetch<ItemCategory, Category>(@"SELECT * FROM ItemCategory LEFT JOIN Category on Category.CategoryId = ItemCategory.CategoryId WHERE ItemId = @0", item.ItemId);


var grouped = from b in itemcategories
               where b.Category.ParentId != null
               group b by b.Category.ParentId ?? 0 into g
               select new Group<int, ItemCategory> { Key = g.Key, Values = g };

public class Group<K,T>
{
    public K Key;
    public IEnumerable<T> Values;
}
```

**In view**

```
@foreach (var group in @Model.ItemCategories)
{
  @group.Key **Category.Name should be displayed here**
}
foreach (var value in group.Values)
{
   @value.Category.Name
}
```

Comment: Can you be more precise what's the issue ? You already have `@value.Category.Name`. Is the problem the fact that you expect `@group.Key` to be the name of the category ?

Comment: Yes, I want @group.key to be the name of the category.

Comment: but that's not possible with the way that you designed your Group class, because the type of `Key` is `int` and the type of `Category.Name` is `string`. So how do we do this ?

Comment: I have tried adding a new property to the group class, but I didn't have any success assigning the Category.Name to that property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the answer provided here:
[Group by in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq).
However, you should also change your DB query so that it returns the actual result of the join and not just an `IEnumerable<ItemCategory>`.
The `Group` class could look like:

```
public class Group<K,T>
{
    public K Key;
    public IEnumerable<T> Values;
    public IEnumerable<string> CategoryNames;
}
```

Note that if you want to group by `ParentId`, your key will always be `ParentId`, it's the idea of the `GroupBy` function.
With that new `Group` class and DB query, you should be able to use `g.Name` as the parameter for `CategoryNames`.